# How do I create a one to many relationship in Parse?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, relation

I'm trying to set up relationships in parse, but I don't know how. For instance, could I get explicit instructions on how I would link the two tables below?

- Branch table consist of objectId, branchName, company, address.
- Company table consist of objectId, companyName.

I would like to make a relation between Branch's company field and Company's objectId field in the manner that If I were to pull a record for a specific Branch, the string in the company field would relate to the objectId in the Company table. In real terms 1 company can have multiple branch's, but a branch can only relate to one company.

I have primarily used Access and understand how to make relationships and calls there, but cant figure out how to do it in parse. Do I need to wrote code in my main.js file? Can I do this from the data tab in my dashboard on parse.com?

Comment: Take a look at https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide#top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationships in Parse are handled through the `Relation` data type. To make a class that uses a relation, do the following:

Go into your Parse account, open the app you want to add this class to.

- Click on 'Core'.
- Click on "data".
- Click "Add Class:

For Class #1, call it `Company`.

- Make sure that class is highlighted on the left side, and click "Add Col":  Add the `companyName` as a column, and choose string as the data type.

Do these same instructions again, this time for the `Branch` class.

Add more columns for the branch class for `branchName` and `address`.  For the company name relation, do the following:

Add a new column. For the "Select a Type" dropdown, choose "Relation";

On the middle dropdown, it will ask you what you want to relate it to, tell it which Parse class (Company), and on the right, name the column (in your case, it would be "CompanyId").

Comment: Followed that and it worked perfectly, thank you. We wanted to import CSV files into the database that were already populated with data so the fields would already be initiated. Can I still use the add new column -> select relation as type method with tables and fields that have already been created?

Comment: I don't know, I suspect so, but I don't know. give it a try.